# Taking screenshot programmatically in mac only for application window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screenshot

I have to add the ability to take screenshots to my OSX apps, but the Apple demo is only giving me the whole screen image, I just want to only my application window image.

My code is:

```
NSInteger displaysIndex = 0;
if(displays != nil)
{
    free(displays);
}


CGError             err = CGDisplayNoErr;
CGDisplayCount      dspCount = 0;

/* How many active displays do we have? */
err = CGGetActiveDisplayList(0, NULL, &dspCount);

/* If we are getting an error here then their won't be much to display. */
if(err != CGDisplayNoErr)
{
    return;
}
/* Allocate enough memory to hold all the display IDs we have. */
displays = calloc((size_t)dspCount, sizeof(CGDirectDisplayID));

// Get the list of active displays
err = CGGetActiveDisplayList(dspCount,
                             displays,
                             &dspCount);

/* Make a snapshot image of the current display. */
CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(displays[displaysIndex]);
```

What should I change in code so I will get only my app's window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple.

```
NSImage *captureImage  = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[self.view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[self.view bounds]]];
```

please check and let me know. This is captured current active window.

Comment: This will capture only the contents of a view and its descendants; even if you address this to the window's content view, it will still exclude the window's frame. Also, you can skip the conversion to and from PDF by locking focus on an image and sending the view a `drawRect:` message (which is generally not otherwise warranted, but in this case appropriate), or by using `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` and the corresponding method of that image rep and adding the rep to an empty image.

Answer (score 7):

To actually take a screenshot of your window, including its frame and shadow, get your window's `windowNumber` and pass that to [the `CGWindowListCreateImage` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/quartz_window_services#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWindowListCreateImage).

Comment: This is a better approach IMO.